# How to no duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I’m making private messages in my website. Everything is okay but I can’t get the list of all the messages that the user sent or received. 
I have 2 tables. `users(id,username,etc..)` and `messages (id,user1,user2,message,date)`

I’ve tried following to get all list messages for one user

> (SELECT DISTINCT * from users WHERE user1 = $userid OR user2 = $userid
>   ORDER BY date ASC)

but I can’t get the messages and I see duplicate values like

User1    User2

```
2            1

1            2
```

I want to get just one value for one relation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but from my interpretation I think this may help remove duplicate rows for each relationship:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages GROUP BY user1,user2
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not working it returns

User1 User2

2            1

1            2

I don’t want to duplicate value